# How to find if this is the first call or second call for a fixture in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to figure out if there are any ways that when I use a fixture and if this is the first time it returns true otherwise returns false.
Let's say:

```
@pytest.fixture( scope = "session" )
def first() :
    # first call should return true
```

The scope I want to test is session and I know this fixture only runs one time per session but I want to modify this behaviour in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the scope you use is **session**, the code in `def first()` **would run once and produce a single object**. However, this returned object can be anything you want and behave in any way you want.

For example, you can return an endless generator which would return `True` the first time and `False` for any additional calls of `next`, like so:

```
import itertools
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def first():
    # first call should return true
    return itertools.chain(itertools.repeat(True, 1), itertools.repeat(False))


def test_one(first):
    assert next(first)


def test_two(first):
    assert not next(first)


def test_three(first):
    assert not next(first)
```

This is how you can distinguish in your tests whether this is the first time.